# How to include Polymer paper-dropdown-menu in form submit

Tags: html, polymer

When I submit this Polymer form with `document.getElementById("form").submit();` firstName and lastName are included in the POST-data, but the title-value from the paper-dropdown-menu not. What is missing ?

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/edit">
    <paper-dropdown-menu name="title" label="Title">
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{titles}}" as="title">
                <paper-item value="{{item.id}}">{{title.name}}</paper-item>
            </template>
        </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <paper-input name="firstName" label="First name"></paper-input>
    <paper-input name="lastName" label="Last name"></paper-input>
    <paper-button raised onclick="submitForm()">Save</paper-button>
</form>
```

**Edit:**

Here my complete working example, thanks a lot to @Brandon for his answer:

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/api/edit">
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Title" selected-item="{{selectedItem}}" selected-item-label="{{selected}}">
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{titles}}" as="title">
                <paper-item value="[[title.id]]">[[title.name]]</paper-item>
            </template>
        </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <input is="iron-input" name="title" type="hidden" value$="[[selectedItem.value]]">
    <paper-input name="firstName" label="First name"></paper-input>
    <paper-input name="lastName" label="Last name"></paper-input>
    <paper-button raised onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">Save</paper-button>
</form>
```

Comment: Might be because `paper-dropdown-menu` doesn't implement `Polymer.IronFormElementBehavior`?

Comment: @Justin XL, by chance do you know if there is a different element which can be used to get a <select>-style element inside a form ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may solve your problem. Create a hidden input element and assign the selected item to the hidden element's value. This gives you the added benefit of the iron-input validators for multi-select for future forms.

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/edit">
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Title" selected-item-label="{{selected}}">
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{titles}}" as="title">
                <paper-item>{{title.name}}</paper-item>
            </template>
        </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <input is="iron-input" name="title" type="hidden" value$="[[selected]]">
    <paper-input name="firstName" label="First name"></paper-input>
    <paper-input name="lastName" label="Last name"></paper-input>
    <paper-button raised onclick="submitForm()">Save</paper-button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it out. Generally I start doubting in the quality of Polymer. Why does it need such a botch to just create a form with a dropdown ?

Comment: You could just use the standard HTML select. But if you want something that looks better than then average form, sometimes it takes a little extra.

Comment: Thank you. Polymer is great but there are so many nuances that its documentation does not capture. This is a lifesaver.

Comment: @Brandon: I tried out your answer and principally it works. But the posted value is actually the label, and not the value of the <paper-item />. Do you know how to get the value of the selected paper-item ?

Comment: Not a problem. using your original paper-item element (with the value attribute) change: 

<paper-dropdown-menu label="Title" selected-item="{{selectedItem}} selected-item-label="{{selected}}">

<input is="iron-input" name="title" type="hidden" value$="[[selectedItem.value]]">

Working sample here: http://jsbin.com/luvuvo/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brandon, you rock.

Comment: Good info, but the dollar sign next to value looks erroneous and should be edited. Let me know if I'm wrong though.

Comment: This is no longer needed, as `iron-form` will handle the `<paper-item>{{title.name}}</paper-item>` natively now when submitting.