# paper-item value not being used in iron-form

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

```
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="foods" name="foods">
      <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="0">
        <paper-item value="1">1+ foods</paper-item>
```

I am using this in a iron form with GET request. It takes `1+ foods` instead of the value for the querystring value. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

[Similar example](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/blob/master/demo/index.html#L80), although it was paper-menu in which I had the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

possible duplicate of [How to include Polymer paper-dropdown-menu in form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926949/how-to-include-polymer-paper-dropdown-menu-in-form-submit)

anyway, you have to create hidden input and assign the selected item to the hidden element's value.

It is great to create property in your custom element which will hold the `selected` param.
so in your case it would be:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="foods" name="foods">
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selected}}" attr-for-selected="value">
    <paper-item value="1">1+ foods</paper-item>
```

as you can see i also used attr-for-selected which is very usefull because it gets the value from attribute you select 
and somewhere after the paper-dropdown-menu:

```
<input is="iron-input" name="food" type="hidden" value$="[[selected]]">
```

then in your serialize function or in get parameters you will have food parameter

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do it without the binding as they did in the example link I posted. 
UPDATE: It appears the value is not being used/working on there ether. Instead, the text of the element is being used.

Comment: Update #2 The above fix/link won't work if the goal is to extract and use the value of `value="1"`. In addition, the above fix/link is no longer needed because as I stated early, `iron-form` will extract the node text and use that value.